# Is there a way to debug another developer app

Tags: android, debugging, ddms

So I know to debug an app you must build a debug version and set debug-able to true. what if I want to debug another developer app is that possible?

Comment: If you have the unencrypted source code, sure.

Comment: @47.5 no I mean like I only have the .APK file

Comment: You can debug the app with crash log, or you can instrument the apk, then run the app, debug with output logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug .apk without actual source code using [apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/).

You can find tutorial [here](http://blog.dornea.nu/2014/08/21/howto-debug-android-apks-with-eclipse-and-ddms/).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot DEBUG with the APK only. You must have the source code to build debug. (You may try decompile it, for research reason only)